# Why my sharedInstance returns nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have viewController with a global property 'notesArray", and I want to get it from AppDelegate through singleton.

Here is my appViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *notesArray;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *notesArray;

+ (AppViewController*)sharedManager;

@end
```

Here is my AppViewController.m

```
@implementation AppViewController

@synthesize notesArray;

+ (AppViewController*)sharedManager {
    static AppViewController *sharedManager;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedManager;
}
...
@end
```

My app works fine, but I need to save it's state in NSUserDefaults, so in AppDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground: I make

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application { 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[AppViewController sharedManager].notesArray forKey:@"savedNotes"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

But the problem is that `[AppViewController sharedManager].notesArray = nil`.
I tried to set breakpoint to applicationDidEnterBackground: and all data from `[AppViewController sharedManager] = nil`.

Comment: Where's your code that attempts to initialize `notesArray`? It will be `nil` until your assign it a value.

Answer (score 0):

Few observations:

1. `notesArray` is not a global property. It is a property on instances of `AppViewController`. Now in #2 we see that you intend it to be a singleton, but since ObjC doesn't really have a good way to prevent someone else from creating a second object of this type, are you sure you're not creating a second copy e.g. by creating an object of that type in a XIB? This is probably not your problem (see #3), but I just wanted to cover all the bases.
2. Your `sharedManager` method implies that you're seeing `AppViewController` as a singleton. That's an unusual thing to do with a view controller. Usually you would have several view controllers, and the singleton would be part of the model they share. Even better, you'd just give each view controller a pointer to the model object that has this array, and if you ever need a second list, everything will just work. Also, why is it called "manager"? It's a view controller.
3. Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see what is going on? What value does `notesArray` have while you're trying to use it in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`? I do not see anywhere in your code that you initialize `notesArray`. So you just have an empty pointer to an object (i.e. `notesArray` is likely `nil`). You probably meant to add an `init` method to your singleton's class that creates an `NSMutableArray` instance and remembers its address in `notesArray`?

Comment: If you're not sure how to use the debugger to see what your program does, this article I wrote a while ago may help: http://masters-of-the-void.com/book12.htm (It's part of a bigger C tutorial, but the things you need to know to debug your own code are the same). I'm currently working on updating it to cover some moved UI elements in newer Xcode releases.

Comment: `sharedManager` might be a strange singleton, but it's a singleton.  Notice that the method is a class method.  The error (based on the code and evidence in the OP) is that notesArray is probably not initialized.